# Добавление сбора статистики в приложение

Tags: java, android, яндекс-метрика

На сей раз решил добавить сбор статистики через Яндекс.Метрика... все скачал, добавил по офиц документации, но на последнем этапе инициализации у них ошибка в документации...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YandexMetrica.initialize(getApplicationContext(), API_KEY);
    }
    ...
}
```

но API_KEY это цифры же, почему они строкой идут (вот [документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/metrica-mobile-sdk/doc/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/android-initialize-docpage)). Пробовал решить проблему путем подставления `String.valueOf`, но приложение даже не открывается...

Может, не в этом проблема? Прикладываю код всех нужных классов и добавок в приложение.

**MyApp**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Application;
import com.yandex.metrica.YandexMetrica;


public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        YandexMetrica.initialize(getApplicationContext(), 9430);
    }
}
```

Также добавил в манифест строчку в application android:name="MyApp".
добавил разрешения, написанные в документации.
Сделал класс MetricaContentProvider

```
package com.example.app;

public class MetricaContentProvider extends com.yandex.metrica.MetricaContentProvider {}
```

Так в чем проблема?
**UPD1**
в LogCat[image: введите описание изображения здесь] ничего нет.Совсем ничего.

**UPD2**
Когда запускаешь в конфигурации простого приложения, logcat заполняется, когда debug configuration, ничего нет. Еще, обнаружил, что если в манифесте удалить строчку `android:name=".MyApp"`, то приложение запускается.
В чем прикол? ту самую ошибку с метрикой исправил, добавил класс stuff

```
    package com.example.app;


public class Stuff {


    public static final String APP_API_KEY = "11111(код изменен)";


}
```

а также теперь MyApp выглядит так:

```
    package com.example.world_train;

import com.yandex.metrica.YandexMetrica;


public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            // Initialize Yandex Metrica
            YandexMetrica.initialize(this, Stuff.APP_API_KEY);
        }

    }
```

**UPD3**
вот код AndroidManifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.app"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <!-- Yandex Metrica required permission. Open network sockets -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- Yandex Metrica required permission. Access information about networks -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- Yandex Metrica optional permission. Approximate location derived from network location sources such as cell towers and Wi-Fi -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Yandex Metrica optional permission. Precise location from location sources such as GPS, cell towers, and Wi-Fi -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Yandex Metrica optional permission. Wifi state: mac, ssid, ... -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <application
android:name=".MyApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo1"

            >

        <service
                android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":Metrica"
                tools:ignore="ExportedService">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService"/>
                <data android:scheme="metrica"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="16"/>
        </service>

        <receiver
                android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.intent.action.SYNC"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
                android:name="com.example.app.MetricaContentProvider"
                android:authorities="com.yandex.sample.metrica.MetricaContentProvider"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"/>
        <!-- Yandex Metrica required manifest entries END -->


        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ScreenOneActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenOne"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenTwo"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenThree"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenFour"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenFourAbout"/>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenFourContacts"/>




    </application>
</manifest>
```

подскажите, в чем дело..

Comment: Вопрос рассчитан на тех, кто имел дело с ЯМ либо недавно, либо прямо сейчас. Притом, видимо, готовых поделиться готовым кодом.   Если бы вы привели информацию об ошибке, которая у вас возникает, возможно, помочь смогли бы и другие участники, для которых java и android являются повседневными занятиями, не обязательно имеющие (или имевшие) дело с ЯМ.

Comment: @Yura , ошибки то толком никакой нет, приложение просто летит при запуске, и я не знаю, в чем причина...

Comment: А вы пробовали LogCat смотреть? Там при падениях не заметить stacktrace ошибки очень сложно. Покажите его нам, и дело скорее всего тронется с мертвой точки.

Comment: Проблемы (лог ошибок) всегда выводятся в LogCat. Посмотрите туда, и проблема решится. Или хотябы выложите сюда лог.

Comment: в документации же параметр указан  (java.lang.String), чего вы число передаете? также есть пример https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-sample-android

Comment: Попробуйте в логкате убрать фильтр - это самое правое поле там где у вас "app: com.example" - поставить "no filter". Если и после этого в логкате будет совсем пусто значит он неправильно подключен.

Comment: @anber  , я обновил вопрос...

Comment: Если удалить в манифесте строчку `android:name=".MyApp"` то onCreate() в классе MyApp вообще не вызовется, так что ошибка в чем-то другом. UPD. provider в манифесте есть?

Comment: @anber ,дбавил код androidmanifest в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста